# Installing Evolution RTS on Linux Steam

Tags: steam, linux

I am trying to install the game Evolution RTS on Steam, but there seems to be a problem downloading the game?

Note, that I have downloaded 0 bytes and yet the installation is complete. I verified the game cache and there was no problem detected.

This game was released on Steam today via Greenlight, so maybe there is a problem with the server?

[image]

Comment: Never mind. I think this might be the issue: 
http://steamcommunity.com/games/291150/announcements/detail/1677896864644842817

Thought not entirely sure.

Comment: Try deleting it and redownloading it.

Comment: I have, still the same problem.

Comment: Does it work for other games?

Comment: @Keavon Yes it does. It's only this game for some reason.

Comment: Try restarting Steam or your computer?

Comment: @Keavon Problem still persists...I'm wondering if anyone who's on Linux can try starting the installation for this.

Answer (score -2):

this game has been around for many years before going to steam. I'd recommend going to http://www.springrts.com or http://www.evolutionrts.info/.

Personally, I'd recommending download spring portable from www.springrts.com, and use springlobby to download evolutionRTS.

Once you get springlobby, click on the battle tab, look for a battle that is EvoRTS, double click to join, it will ask you if it should download map and game, and click yes.

Comment: How many years has it been around for? It seems like it's only been a few months since they released it.

Comment: I think you're confusing the game engine (which indeed has been around since 2004) with the game МикроПингвин was referring to.